# Outlook Reply then delete mail Item

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2010

This piece of code is a bit rough but it is only a mock up. What it basic does is:

When an email comes in from my email and the subject line starts with 'batch':

- copies email to another folder
- replies to email
- deletes original email

At the moment is is doing everything I want apart from delete the email at the end. After I have replied to the email and can't seem to get hold of the original email object to delete it. I know it will be something simple but I can't see it.....

```
Sub Check_For_Ticket(MyMail As MailItem)
Dim mysubject As String
Dim strEmail As String

'On Error GoTo Ticketerror

myemail = "pb***********@hotmail.com"
mysubject = "Batch*"

strEmail = MyMail.SenderEmailAddress
strSubject = MyMail.Subject
If strEmail = myemail And strSubject Like mysubject Then
    MsgBox "yes" & strSubject
    Call pbMoveMessageToTestFolder(MyMail)
    Call AutoReply(MyMail)
Else
    MsgBox "no" & strSubject
End If

MsgBox "this email is: " & strSubject
'Ticketerror:
'    MsgBox "There is an error "
'    MsgBox Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description
End Sub
Sub pbMoveMessageToTestFolder(MyMail As MailItem)

' Works on one selected item

    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myItem As Object
    Dim objcopy As Object

        MsgBox "into 2nd sub"

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    ' Add As many  .Folders("SubfolderName")  as needed
    Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("To_Process")
    Set myItem = MyMail
    'Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item (1)

    Dim copy As Object
    Set copy = myItem.copy
    'move copy to folder
    copy.Move myDestFolder

        MsgBox "should of copied"

    Set myNameSpace = Nothing
    Set myInbox = Nothing
    Set myDestFolder = Nothing
    Set myItem = Nothing

End Sub
Sub AutoReply(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)
'declaring variables
Dim olOutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olOutMail2 As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strpbsubject As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim Str As String

Str = olItem.Subject

MsgBox "3rd sub - subject: " & Str

strpbsubject = "This is an auto-reply from ***, confirming that " & strMid & " has been successfully received at " & Format(DateTime.Now, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")


'Creating the reply email

    With olItem
        Set olOutMail2 = olItem.Reply
        With olOutMail2
            .Body = strpbsubject 'Placing the body of the email in place
            .Subject = "Delivered: " & Str 'appending "Delivered" to the subject line
            .Send        ' This is a changeable variable to display the reply change to .Display
                        ' to deliver the response change to .Send
            .UnRead = True 'makes the email unread after the  auto response is sent
        End With
    Set olOutMail2 = Nothing



    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `MyMail.Delete` after `Call AutoReply(MyMail)`

```
If strEmail = myEmail And mysubject Like mysubject Then
    MsgBox "yes" & mysubject
    Call pbMoveMessageToTestFolder(MyMail)
    Call AutoReply(MyMail)
    MyMail.Delete
Else
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that and come back tomorrow with an update, as I am sure that it do not work when i tried it last time. However I was thinking, would it would if I could just move the email object to the deleted folder? Then ran a macro which cleared the deleted folder?

Comment: @Paul MyMail.Delete moves the item to deleted folder

Comment: Thanks Om3r, finally got it working this afternoon, I'll post the code tomorrow. But just another quick question. If you notice right at the svtart of the code where I am setting the from email. I am doing it in the first sub-routine. I really want to separate this into a routine of it's own. I thought that I could do it in the global variables, but that does not work, would in have to delare them (really want the  myemail & mysubject) in a public function?

Comment: @Paul are calling this from outlook rule?

Comment: yes I am, but I was trying to do all the rules in via rather than put them in the outlook rules if that is possible....